# Rolling back a bad version of the add-in

Tags: office-js

If I have a published an Office Add-in (in my specific case it's an Outlook Add-in), released a new version, and realized that there's a bug in the new version.

Is there a mechanism in the Add-in framework that lets me un-publish and go back one version?

Is the best way just revert the code, and re-publish the next version?

Answer (score 1):

as the model is just a manifest which references your web app, which means you can in most cases rollback the afflicting change on your js directly (hopefully you have version control on your end so it is easier to rollback).

Thanks

Comment: Yes, we have version control tools and that would be possible to do, but I'm wondering about the policy here.

1) This would mean the same manifest version suddenly points to a different version of the web app -- is this allowed?
2) If we update our manifest to fall back a version -- is manifest version going forward enforced? Or can we simply submit an earlier version of the manifest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my ideas too.

Whatever the framework you are in

1. Always create production build, fallback build and Dev/QA Build. Your fallback build should be clean copy of working production version.
2. You can update your manifest to fallback build until you fix your bug.

Some ground rules to remember:

1. Add your version control version number somewhere in your add-in  to identify which build has bug.
2. As suggested by @Keyur. You must definitely have git or any versioning system enabled. So you can either do `reverse commit` or quickly `stash` your changes to the desired branch.

Hope it will give some ideas for you to maintain your add-in going forward

Comment: Yes, we definitely do all of those.
However, updating the manifest takes 3~5 days to wait for approval. I'm wondering if there's a quicker way to say "Oops please go back to previous version" without that manual approval process.

Comment: may be this seems like a bit of hacky way. In your add-in you can have some where place your icon pointing to fallback url and in your help link. You can put the text "Oops click here if you face any problem". This will take them to fallback URL and the relevant routes.